# Wrong verification with Pedersen verifiable secret sharing

Tags: secret-sharing

According to section 4.2 of [Pedersen's verifiable secret sharing](https://reaction.la/security/pedersons_secret_sharing.pdf), given a secret share $(s_i, t_i)$, it is possible to verify that the secret share is valid by using the commitments $E_j$, for $j=0,\ldots,k-1$, by using the formula

$E(s_i, t_i) = E_0 \cdot E_1^{x_i} \cdots E_{k-1}^{x_i^{k-1}}$, i.e. $g^{s_i}h^{t_i}=g^{a_0}h^{b_0} \cdot (g^{a_1}h^{b_1})^{x_i} \cdots (g^{a_{k-1}}h^{b_{k-1}})^{x_i^{k-1}}$.

The following Go method performs the verification step according to Pedersen VSS:

```
type SecretPart struct {
    s *big.Int
    t *big.Int
}

type Pedersen struct {
    threshold int
    p         *big.Int
    g         *big.Int
    h         *big.Int
}

func (p Pedersen) verify(abscissa *big.Int,
    part SecretPart,
    commitments []*big.Int,
) error {
    pMinus := new(big.Int).Sub(p.p, big.NewInt(1))
    // rhs = E_0 * E_1^x * ... * E_j^{x^j}
    rhs := new(big.Int).Set(commitments[0])
    xPow := big.NewInt(1)
    for j := 1; j < p.threshold; j++ {
        xPow.Mul(xPow, abscissa).Mod(xPow, pMinus)
        term := new(big.Int).Exp(commitments[j], xPow, p.p)
        rhs.Mul(rhs, term).Mod(rhs, p.p)
    }

    // lhs = g^s * h^t
    term1 := new(big.Int).Exp(p.g, part.s, p.p)
    term2 := new(big.Int).Exp(p.h, part.t, p.p)

    lhs := new(big.Int).Mul(term1, term2)
    lhs.Mod(lhs, p.p)

    if lhs.Cmp(rhs) != 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("wrong secret part: lhs=%s != rhs=%s", lhs, rhs)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Despite the procedure is straightforward, the verification step always fails having the left-hand side term different from the right-hand side one.

Here is a [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/7bMvjd8Autp) with a running show case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $g$ and $h$ are **not** generators of the subgroup of order $q = (p-1)/2$ (in your implementation, you have $p=83$, $q=41$, $g=2$, and $h=8$). The order of $g$ and $h$ is $p-1 = 82$ rather than $q=41$.

For Pedersen commitments, you want to work in the group of order $q$, which requires using $g=3$ and $h=7$ and setting your "pMinus1" variable to be $q=41$ (when using your toy parameter $p=83$).